# Cant access member of object

Tags: javascript, object, numbers, leaflet, member

I have an issue to access a member in the object DOM, because the object name is a number!

I am working with `leaflet.js` and I created a layer with a path. Now I want to access the polylines latLngs. In this case I wanna access the layer "100".
The variables are configurable and writable. Anybody an idea how to get access ?

I tried this with no success:

```
routingLayer._layers[100]._latlng
```

Error:

> routingLayer._layers[100] is undefined

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Report the error you're getting in details.

Comment: routingLayer._layers[100] is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
routingLayer._layers["100"]._latlng
```

Comment: According to  [§11.2.1 Property Accessors](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.1) this should not be necessary because at step 6 the value inside the brackets is stringified with [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8).

Comment: @Oriol I have to agree, this answer is *wrong* and misleading. If selman's problem is solved, it must have been for something else and maybe should be properly addressed.